# Why grep "invert match" command-line option is named "-v"?

Tags: command-line, grep, command-line-arguments

What's the meaning of `-v`?

Is it the first letter of some meaningful word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, both commands and its options tend to be quite logical. You `find` something that you then may want to `c`o`p`y somewhere else once you `m`a`k`e a `dir`, etc.

In `grep`, together with many other commands, you have the long `--option` and the short `-o` that come in pairs. For this specific case, in `man grep` you can see that **`-v` is equivalent to `--invert-match`**.

Since `-i` is for `ignore case` and `n` logically goes to `line-number`, I think `v` is the most representative word that was still available from the word `invert`.

`man grep` excerpt:

> -v, --invert-match
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is
>   specified by POSIX.)

Comment: The beginning is not logical. You `find` something and `c`o`p`y it? Why not `f`i`nd` something and  `c`o`p`y it? Or `find` something and `copy` it? Or `m`a`k`e a`d`i`r`?

Comment: Well, you are right and in fact this reminds me of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/258656/1983854) quoting http://www.mindspring.com/~blackhart/requium.html: _I have only been able to come up with one algorithm for creating Unix command names: think of a good English word to describe what you want to do, then think of an obscure near- or partial-synonym, throw away all the vowels, arbitrarily shorten what's left, and then, finally, as a sop to the literate programmer, maybe reinsert one of the missing vowels._ So it is *kind* of logic, only that some logic falls in the process.